# How to setup multiple layered discount?

Tags: admin, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I am trying to set up a **discount** for my **store** as follows:

**First item:** No discount

**Second item:** 20% Off for the whole cart

**Third item:** 50% Off for the whole cart

May I know how to set this up?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using Magento 1.x.

You can manage above conditions by **Shopping Cart Price Rules**.

- To do so, go to **`Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules`**.
- Click on "**Add New Rule**" button.
- Under Rule Information tab, provide values for **Rule Name** and
  **description**. Set Status **Active**. Select Customer Groups for which you want to allow the discount. Select **No Coupon** for coupon section.
- Under Conditions tab, you should set conditions like below:

> If **ANY** of these conditions are **TRUE**:
>
> Total Items Quantity  **is**  **2**.

- Under Actions tab, put below values:

**Apply:** Percent of product price discount

**Discount Amount: *** 20

**Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To ** 2

**Discount Qty Step (Buy X):** 0

**Apply to Shipping Amount:** Yes

**Free Shipping:** No

**Stop Further Rules Processing:** Yes

I have mentioned the process of adding the condition for a discount on 2 products. You can add similar rules for other conditions also.

Please let me know if it worked for you.